# Could not resolve matching constructor but constructor seem fine

Tags: spring, constructor, weblogic12c

We currently have an application that uses a class called JmsComponentMessageDispatcher to look after putting messages on to queues here is the constructor.

```
public JmsComponentMessageDispatcher(ConnectionFactory cf, FileDataAccess access, 
        List<Destination> destinations)
{
    if (cf == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (access == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (destinations == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    m_cf = cf;
    m_access = access;
    m_destinations = Collections.unmodifiableList(destinations);
}

public JmsComponentMessageDispatcher(ConnectionFactory cf, FileDataAccess access, Destination destination)
{
    this(cf, access, Collections.singletonList(destination));
}

public JmsComponentMessageDispatcher(ConnectionFactory cf, FileDataAccess access)
{
    this(cf, access, Collections.<Destination>emptyList());
}
```

Normally this would be setup in the application context

```
    <bean id="componentMessageDispatcher" abstract="true" 
    class="com.core.jms.JmsComponentMessageDispatcher" scope="prototype"
    c:_0-ref="jmsCF"
    c:_1-ref="fileDataAccess"/>
```

We are porting our application to weblogic and for some reason weblogic intermittently loads the wrong concrete class for the connection factory.  See here: [A JMS XA connection factory injected using spring jee-jndi lookup behaves differently than @Resource injection on Weblogic 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957719/a-jms-xa-connection-factory-injected-using-spring-jee-jndi-lookup-behaves-differ)

To try and work round this issue I plan to inject the connection factory using @Resource.
I created a new class WeblogicJmsComponentMessageDispatcher that extends JmsComponentMessageDispatcher.  It simply takes in a bean as parameter this bean has the connection factory loaded using @Resource.

```
public class WeblogicJmsComponentMessageDispatcher extends 

JmsComponentMessageDispatcher
{
    public WeblogicJmsComponentMessageDispatcher(WeblogicConnectionFactoryLocal wcf, FileDataAccess access)
    {
        super(wcf.getConnectionFactory(), access, Collections.<Destination>emptyList());
    }
}
```

bean:

```
@Stateless(name="WeblogicConnectionFactoryBean")
@Local(WeblogicConnectionFactoryLocal.class)
public class WeblogicConnectionFactoryBean implements WeblogicConnectionFactoryLocal{

    @Resource(mappedName="jms/mf_ConnectionFactory")    
    private ConnectionFactory m_cf;

    public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory()
    {
        return m_cf;
    }
```

Application Context:

```
<beans profile="weblogic">  
    <bean id="componentMessageDispatcher" class="com.core.jms.WeblogicJmsComponentMessageDispatcher">
        <constructor-arg name="wcf" ref="wlCF"/>
        <constructor-arg name="access" ref="fileDataAccess"/>
    </bean>

    <jee:local-slsb id="wlCF" jndi-name="java:module/WeblogicConnectionFactoryBean!com.core.jms.WeblogicConnectionFactoryLocal"
        business-interface="com.core.jms.WeblogicConnectionFactoryLocal"/>
```

If I step through it in debug, I can see the constructors getting hit and presenting the correct values however I'm getting the Could not resolve matching constructor error.

```
<12-Jan-2016 11:28:58 o'clock GMT> <Error> <Deployer> <WL-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "701665806559063" for task "25". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'componentMessageDispatcher$child#1959023' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'componentMessageDispatcher$child#1959023' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'componentMessageDispatcher$child#1959023' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.access.ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.initializeDefinition(ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:381)
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.getBeanFactoryReference(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.doAutowireBean(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.invokeLifecycleMethod(Jsr250Metadata.java:377)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.proceed(LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.java:115)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.proceed(LifecycleEventCallbackInvocationContext.java:144)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.InterceptionMetadata.invokeLifecycleMethods(InterceptionMetadata.java:463)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EjbComponentCreatorImpl.invokePostConstruct(EjbComponentCreatorImpl.java:55)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.constructAndInitBean(SingletonSessionManager.java:330)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.access$300(SingletonSessionManager.java:62)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.doActualInit(SingletonSessionManager.java:753)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.initInternal(SingletonSessionManager.java:701)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.init(SingletonSessionManager.java:588)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.init(SingletonSessionManager.java:255)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.perhapsInit(SingletonSessionManager.java:251)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.start(EJBDeployer.java:968)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.start(EJBModule.java:597)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
>
```

I’ve mocked this up on a small test application and it works perfectly.  So I must have done something incorrectly but for the life of me I can't see what it is.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities"

Did you try that? Maybe it's getting confused between your `List<Destination>` and `Destination`  constructors.

It would be a matter of adding `type="..."` to your `<constructor-arg ...>` tag

See http://www.mkyong.com/spring/constructor-injection-type-ambiguities-in-spring/

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply.  Based on your response I tried two things.  Firstly I added in the type to the constructor tags.  Unfortunately the error is still the same.  Secondly as a test I removed all but the first constructor from the JmsComponentMessageDispatcher class.  Again unfortunately the error is the same.

Comment: Was worth trying... Unfortunately, my spring days are a few years behind! I'd ask you another question : Can you access any other constructor in this `weblogic` profile? Maybe the profile is not loaded correctly. And did the mock application you speak of had such a profile?

Comment: Hi Thanks again.  Yes I can access other constructors in this profile.  As a test I tried removing all profiles but I'm still getting the same error.